# css transition calculating lag w/ jQuery scrollLeft animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm working on this concept:

[codepen.io/dkpen/pen/rxRNaL?editors=0010](http://codepen.io/dkpen/pen/rxRNaL?editors=0010)

Concept is about a magnification effect (on the circle) and scroll change position. the problem is that when you click on the click me! button the css transition lags in all browsers -- it is a bit better in firefox --. what do you think how could i eliminate this lagging w/o changing the concept (so the `margin-left`, `top` and`scrolltop` position etc).

Comment: For me In FF, Chrome, and Safari the animation is quite smooth. That said, it is ill advised to use the animate method on anything other than scale, rotate, opacity, and position (dont animate margin to re-position, animate Top, Bottom, Left, Right for positioning). Animating any other properties is at your own risk as not all browsers support animating the same properties and any animation that forces the engine to recalculate and redraw layout tends to be processor intensive. It seems that the problem may be the processing capabilities of your computer using the animate method as you are.